# Does the Prothean squadmate have significance outside of in-quest commentary?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I played through the Eden Prime mission and watched his back story, but is the rest of his inclusion in the main story similar to Kasumi or Zaeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's more similar to your normal squad members than the previous DLC party members were.

He has interactive dialog sequences just like normal squadmates.

He has scenes where he interacts with other crew members over the comms.

You can also talk to him aboard the Citadel where you can use a Paragon interrupt to convince him to give an inspirational speech to an Assari, Turian, and Hanar.

Comment: rather disappointing. thanks though!

Comment: @Haydener - Out of curiosity, why is this disappointing?  It's a lot more than you got out of the last DLC characters...

Comment: dont get me wrong, i think javik is an awesome character, but the scope of his dlc is kind of meh. giving that he's the only prothean in the galaxy, you'd think he would be a bigger deal. other than his dialogue, everything from the eden prime mission to the cutscene on the citadel seems sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

Javik has some unique dialogue so you should talk to him between missions and have him in your squad more often. Especially on the **Priority: Thessia** mission - you will learn some pretty interesting stuff about the Asari only he can tell you.

Javik is your only source to the "previous cycle" and he can give you a different perspective on things. IMO he has a lot more "significance" than just the Eden Prime mission.

[Here is a more complete list of Javik's commentary (contains minor spoilers).](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Javik/Unique_dialogue)